# A Workload Scheduler's step doesn't proceed and remains queued status

Tags: scheduler, ibm-cloud, workload

I created a simple process by Applicaiton Lab interface in Bluemix Workload Scheduler. I ran my process, but the step didn't proceed and remained in queued status.

How can I proceed the step?

**I executed the process by "Run now". The process doesn't have triggers**
[image]

**The step remains "Queued status".**
[image]

**The Process information**

- There is only one step. The step is "ping www.ibm.com"
  [image]
  [image]
- Process doesn't have trigger. It is an on-demand process.
  [image]

Comment: Could you give some details more about the scheduling?

Comment: Hi. Thank you for you response. I didn't create triggers. I would like to execute the process when I click "Run now" in Application Lab interface. Doesn't "Run now" and no triggers mean executing the step right now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a problem with the agent as I can successfully run a simple workload process without any issues. If you are using the Workload Automation Agent that is created for you then you will need to open a [support ticket](https://cloudoe.support.ibmcloud.com/ics/support/default.asp?deptid=31036&offering=ibmbluemix) to have the Workload team look at that agent.

Answer (score 0):

reviewing your question I think that a process submitted to the Workload Scheduler service should be a process which will complete: a ping command like the one you are trying to submit, will never complete if not 'killed' using CTRL+C (or called with [-c count] option)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I carelessly created ping command step without count option. It was revealed that the threshold number of jobs are running in the agent by Bluemix support team. So new jobs are in queued status.